# Update "status" cell if visit_date is < todays date php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with holiday destinations in with a visit_date column and a status column. 
visit date is when they plan to go/or have been to this destination. When these holidays are being inserted into database, I wrote this to determine if the people are going or have been on this trip.

```
$date = $_POST['date']; 
$today = date("Y/m/d");  

if($date<$today){
$status="been";
}else{
$status="going";
}
```

But what I need to do is write a script that runs after the insert to update the status of the old holiday plans from going to been if the visit_date is less than todays date as in yesterday, last week etc..

this is what I have so far

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trips");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  //echo $row['visit_date'];

  if ($row['visit_date'] < $today){
      echo "this trip has already happened";
      //code to update status if trip already happened

  }
  }
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
UPDATE trips
SET status = 'been'
WHERE status = 'going' AND visit_date < NOW()
```

But you know what would even be better? Get rid of of the `status` column. Then whenever you need to select trips and want to figure out their status, use a conditional `IF` statement like so:

```
SELECT
    trip_id,
    IF(visit_date < NOW(), 'been', 'going') AS status,
    ...
FROM trips
```